# No token in google.auth credentials for aws workload identity federation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, workload-identity

Why would the code below result in no token in returned credentials? (WIF pool with aws provider exist and service account connected to it)

```
from google.auth import aws

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    json_config_info = {
      "type": "external_account",
      "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/XXX/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/awspool/providers/awsprovider",
      "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:aws:token-type:aws4_request",
      "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/serviceaccount@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
      "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
      "credential_source": {
        "environment_id": "aws1",
        "region_url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone",
        "url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials",
        "regional_cred_verification_url": "https://sts.{region}.amazonaws.com?Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15"
      }
    }

    credentials = aws.Credentials.from_info(json_config_info)
    print('token: ', credentials.token)
    print('valid: ', credentials.valid)
```

I'm getting token=None and valid=False while my understanding credentials should have a token and valid=True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to perform a refresh of your credential to effectively perform a request to Google Cloud. Something like this

```py
from google.auth import aws

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    json_config_info = {
      "type": "external_account",
      "audience": "//iam.googleapis.com/projects/XXX/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/awspool/providers/awsprovider",
      "subject_token_type": "urn:ietf:params:aws:token-type:aws4_request",
      "service_account_impersonation_url": "https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/projects/-/serviceAccounts/serviceaccount@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com:generateAccessToken",
      "token_url": "https://sts.googleapis.com/v1/token",
      "credential_source": {
        "environment_id": "aws1",
        "region_url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone",
        "url": "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials",
        "regional_cred_verification_url": "https://sts.{region}.amazonaws.com?Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15"
      }
    }

    credentials = aws.Credentials.from_info(json_config_info)

    ### Code added
    import google.auth.transport.requests
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    creds.refresh(request)
    ### Code end

    print('token: ', credentials.token)
    print('valid: ', credentials.valid)
```